# Creating n child process in c using fork

Tags: c, operating-system

I found this code in geeks4geeks and i can't seem to understand it properly:

```
#include<stdio.h> 


int main() 
{ 
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) // loop will run n times (n=5) 
    {  pid_t c=fork();
        if(c == 0) 
        { 
            printf("[son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n",getpid(),getppid()); 
            exit(0); 
        } 
    } 
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) // loop will run n times (n=5) 
    wait(NULL); 

}
```

This code creates 5 processes from a father process and prints a message from each child.My question is this:Since we haven't used any restriction for c  isn't for example the second fork executed by both father and first child process?Without  isolating  fork inside father's code how does this code not create 2^5 child processes?Is the for loop somehow stopping this from happening?

Comment: Your children `exit` right after created, how can they execute `fork`?

Comment: The key thing to note is that the return value for `fork()` in the child process is 0 and in the parent process is the pid of the child.  So, in the child process, the if test is true, and the print statement is executed and the process exits.  If the parent process, the if test is false and the loop continues and forks another child process.

Comment: It's not a "son", it's a "child".  It's not a "father", it's a "parent".  Processes are genderless.

Answer (score 8):

The child processes don't call `fork` because they exit before that happens:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{   
    pid_t c=fork();
    if(c == 0)  // fork returns 0 to the child process so it enters "if" block
    { 
        printf("[son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n",getpid(),getppid()); 
        // child exits
        exit(0); 
    } 
}
```

If the `if` block did not contain `exit` then yes each child would iterate back to the top of the loop and potentially `fork` again.  But since each child exits right after printing only the initial parent process calls `fork`, so you only create 5 processes.

Answer (score 2):

`fork()` returns 0 in the child process, while in the parent process it returns the PID of the child. Since the `c` has a value of 0 in the child, `if(c == 0)` will evaluate to true, the child will execute the `printf` statement, and then exit. It will never reach the loop evaluation statement.

Answer (score 0):

In this program, they use exit(0), so the child process is exiting after it creation.